lsusb is hanging
OS is Debian 12. I have all usb devices unplugged. Connected via ssh.
If I run lsusb, for some reason some of the previously connected usb devices get listed (again, even though all usb devices are unplugged), and then lsusb hangs.
When I run strace, as it attaches to the lsusb process, lsusb prints out another line! Very strange. strace then prints out:
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/bus/usb/devices/3-3/product", O_RDONLY) =
read(8,

Then when I ctrl+c out of strace, lsusb finishes printing the rest of its output. Also seems very odd.
No errors in dmesg.
All usb ports seem to work fine, with the exception of the two usb 3.0 ports on the motherboard which don't seem to be working now.
Could the usb 3.0 driver be buggy? I'm just guessing at this point.
How do I restart the usb subsystem without rebooting? Or is there another way to fix this without rebooting?

When it hangs, can you successfully SIGKILL lsub ? (that would confirm if it is lost into some uninterruptible syscall what your strace experiment suggests.)


Could the usb 3.0 driver be buggy? I'm just guessing at this point.

That, or the firmware. Certainly looks like it.

How do I restart the usb subsystem without rebooting? Or is there another way to fix this without rebooting?

Like this

Thank you. Is there a way to do this on a kernel module level? ie, one command to unload and reload all usb related kernel modules and deps?

No, not that I'm aware of. It would probably also be a really really bad idea to do that, seeing how central USB has become for the workings of your PC.
